# Convert Store Procedure Result Set into XML string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have `GetProductDetailedDescriptions` stored procedure. I want to create a function that returns the result set of `GetProductDetailedDescriptions` into xml string in sql. I have tried,

```
EXEC [GetProductDetailedDescriptions] @pid FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS
```

But I am getting syntax error.

Comment: what is the syntax error?

Comment: @NeilHosey, Acyually I cannot run sp inside function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a T-SQL function you can not modify data in permanent tables and can not execute stored procedure. This is by design.

You can write and use CLR-function to call stored proc from it or use OPENROWSET with a loopback linked server, but this approach isn't advised